# R how to plot series of matrices "using image.plot" with a fixed color scale?

Tags: r, field

```
library(fields)

Li <- list(matrix(1,2,2), matrix(2,2,2), matrix(3,2,2))

image.plot(matrix((data=Li[[1]]), ncol=2, nrow=2))
image.plot(matrix((data=Li[[1]]), ncol=2, nrow=2))
image.plot(matrix((data=Li[[1]]), ncol=2, nrow=2))
```

I do not want that that the legend gets automatically adjusted in every plot,
I would like to have a fixed range of color varying from 0-10.

thank you!
Ilmari

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to read the help page and then use the 'col' and 'breaks' parameters as described there:

```
Li <- list(matrix(4,2,2), matrix(2,2,2), matrix(3,2,2))
png()
image.plot(matrix( (data=Li[[1]]), ncol=2, nrow=2), col=colors()[1:10], breaks=0:10)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I would like to ask you how to set the scale into a grayscale, from white to black?